# Xen Dom0's networking lost, guests OK

Tags: debian, xen

So I had to unplug the Xen server's NIC. When I was done, I plugged it back in, and attempted to SSH into it. Fails. But my connections to the guests work perfectly fine. They're still up and running with the extra IP address.

**The HOST is not!** Dom0 has no network connection, as far as it's concerned.

The `xenbr0` adapter has the correct address that it should, but it cannot ping anything on the local network. `route` shows the correct gateway address for the network (it's assigned via `/etc/network/interfaces` anyways). The guests have their regular IP addresses, and I can connect to them OK. Running `ifup xenbr0` or `ifup eth0` returns a message that it's already up. *I don't want to take them down, if possible*.

Other than restarting, what do you suppose the issue is, and how to fix? I just want to see if I can fix it without a reboot. Both Debian-based OSes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I still had `eth0` as an auto-connection with DHCP. It got plugged in, grabbed the same IP address, and had a conflict.

I solved this by editing `/etc/network/interfaces`, and changing the line:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

to

```
iface eth0 inet manual
```

I then took down `eth0` (`ifdown eth0`) and brought it back up (`ifup eth0`). Then I could ping systems and access it from SSH.